# Robot Framework cannot create folder via Create Folder keyword

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I observe very strange situation my Robot Framework script cannot create folder via Create Directory keyword. Code is very simple

```
Create Directory   folder_name
```

According to log step ends with success but actually folder is not created.
I use Robot Framework 3.2.2 on latest version of xubuntu. I suppose that something wrong with access to file system from script. But I cannot fond out where

Comment: could you provide the errors?

Comment: I assume you are using OperatingSystem Library, correct? Are you providing absolute or relative path? The path where you are trying to create directory, does your user have update access permissions? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: command return zero code the step is green, but no folder created

Answer (score 0):

Please use double slashes (**//**)
to separate the folders forming the **path** argument
("folder_name", as you've named it).

This notation is for Windows.
The idea can be explored from here on.